# Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед тире в таком предложении: "Я знал: это из-за меня - и казалось, что даже в конце жизни я опять что-то сделал не так..." 
Мне почему-то хочется поставить, но я не уверена.

Comment: @sejsenagon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Я бы вместо тире поставил точку с запятой. Или точку.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение разделено на два смысловых отрезка, поэтому возможны и тире, и точка с запятой, и точка, и запятая и тире как единый знак. Только запятая и тире как единый знак как бы устарели, так принято было ставить в 19-начале 20 века. Если это нужно для оценки, лучше следовать современной пунктуации и обойтись тире (или точкой с запятой).